# Is it possible to populate a spinner in android using a JSONArray?

Tags: android, json, spinner

Just as the title says.. Is it possible to do this?  Say I have a JSON array of something like this

```
{
    "locations": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "loc": "miami"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "loc": "manhattan"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "loc": "lasVegas"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, extend `BaseAdapter` and use the `JSONArray` as your backing model. However, it would be better (but by no means necessary) to convert it to a more "natural" representation in Java and use that instead.

Comment: would it affect performance either negatively or positively if i use a baseadapeter class, compared with using a more natural java representation??

Comment: The `BaseAdapter` way has no intrinsic performance issues, having the data in a `JSONArray` vs a normal array does affect performance, since it has to do the conversion for each element.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the json to a java object. and bind the data.